# How To Get Peer Associated Nodes in Alfresco 5.0 using Java?

Tags: java, alfresco

I'm using alfresco 5, Deleting a node should result in some modifications on its peer connected nodes, I've implemented the `NodeServicePolicies.BeforeDeleteNodePolicy` but can't find a way to retrieve the associated nodes, I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011423/how-to-get-related-peer-association-nodes-programatically-in-alfresco-using-ja) answer that suggests using `NodeUtils.getTargetAssociatedNodeRef` which seems unavailable in alfresco 5.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the nodeservice you can use this:

```
nodeService.getTargetAssocs(nodeRef, RegexQNamePattern.MATCH_ALL)
```